# How can I change my personal information on Blizzard account?

Tags: battle.net

I want to change my Name/Last name on my Blizzard account as, because of some childishness of mine, I didn't put my real name, but a nickname instead (and I used the same nickname on my last name).

I looked around and found some information, but not the proper way on how do I do this. Can somebody help me on this one?

Comment: Related [Changing name on Battle.net account.](http://blog.tgs.net/index.php/changing-name-on-battle-net-account/) be careful =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the method would be to contact Blizzard's Customer Support Service by telephone. The number should be listed on their website. You will likely also be asked to provide by fax or email at least one form of photo identification. This is the same method used to turn off Parental Controls on your account, or to prove your YOU in the event that Blizzard feels your account has been hacked or otherwise stolen.

Remember, Blizzard employees will NEVER ask you for your password. (something to keep in mind during times such as these)

Comment: Because you're asked to provide official documentation, I'm assuming that there's therefore no way to do this in reverse, correct? As in, if you've already put in your legal name, you cannot change it to something else that's more nickname-like or somesuch?

Comment: @Fae I have no idea. That answer would likely be found within their Terms of Use Agreement, some concept of how accurate they want their information on you to be.

Answer (score 4):

*As a complement for [@Ender's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102214/12936). Here is a Ticket that I submit to blizzard.*

---

### The reply

> Greetings!
>
> The first and last name on the account can only be changed by us, in
>   this case I'd highly recommend you contact us for more information
>   directly over the phone.
>
> Hopefully the information will help out, but if you need more
>   assistance, I'd like to reiterate that you can always resubmit a
>   ticket or give us a call directly.
>
> We're here daily between 7am and 8pm Pacific Time, at
>   1-800-59-BLIZZARD (800-592-5499). Customers in Australia should call
>   1-800-041-378.

Answer (score 0):

I also registered with a fake name on Battle.net and after something like 20 support emails, these lovely guys from Blizzard told me that there were NO WAY for me to change my account's personnal data EXCEPT if I provide a copy of my identity card.

So I would say that you'll have to provide a genuine id before the accept to change anything.